# C# - Lambda / LINQ - Conversion From Dictionary<string, string>[] to List<string[]>

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, lambda

Long story short, what I am trying to achieve is to convert a `Dictionary<string, string>[]` to a `List<string[]>`. I dont mind losing the key information of the dictionaries.

The solution which I came up is working but I am pretty sure there is a fancier way to accomplish the same result with LINQ and Lambda expressions.

I especially hate the part where I need to use an additional variable for the count but as far as I know, it's not possible to loop through a `Dictionary<string, string>` with a `for` loop

Thanks in advance.

```
 Dictionary<string, string>[] arrayOfStringDictionaries = new Dictionary<string, string>[2]
        {
            new Dictionary<string, string>(),
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
        };

        arrayOfStringDictionaries[0].Add("1", "Test1");
        arrayOfStringDictionaries[0].Add("2", "Test2");
        arrayOfStringDictionaries[0].Add("3", "Test3");

        arrayOfStringDictionaries[1].Add("1", "Test4");
        arrayOfStringDictionaries[1].Add("2", "Test5");
        arrayOfStringDictionaries[1].Add("3", "Test6");

        List<string[]> listofStringArrays = new List<string[]>();

        foreach (Dictionary<string, string> singledic in arrayOfStringDictionaries)
        {
            int count = 0;
            string[] stringArray = new string[singledic.Keys.Count];
            foreach (var key in singledic.Keys)
            {
                stringArray[count] = singledic[key];
                count++;
            }

            listofStringArrays.Add(stringArray);
        }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So all you want is the values?

```
arrayOfStringDictionaries.Select(dict => dict.Values.ToArray()).ToList();
```

What this basically means:

- For each dictionary in the array, get all its values, and make an array of them
- Get all these arrays, and put them into a list